# What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What does `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]` mean when using **`executeScript()`** method from *JavascriptExecutor* interface through Selenium WebDriver and what is the purpose of the `arguments[0]` in the below code.

```
javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webElement);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [**executeScript()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method from the [**JavascriptExecutor**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) Interface can invoke multiple arguments in the form of *arguments[0]*, *arguments[1]*, etc

- As per your example, to `javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webElement);` to work you need to have the *webElement* defined. `executeScript()` method will take the reference of the element as ***arguments[0]*** along with the ***method*** to be performed [in this case `click()`] and the reference should be provided thereafter.

  ```
  WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_element"));
  JavascriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webElement);
  ```
- Similarly, an example of `executeScript()` with multiple *arguments[]* is as follows :

  ```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1])", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")), "0");
  ```

  Here in this example :

  - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']` is referred as **arguments[0]**
  - "0" is referred as **arguments[1]**

> You can find a relevant discussion in [What is arguments[0] while invoking execute_script() method through WebDriver instance through Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273298/what-is-arguments0-while-invoking-execute-script-method-through-webdriver-in/52280298#52280298)

Comment: Finally, an answer that answers the question - javaScriptExecutor.executeScript("`arguments[0]`.click()", `webElement`); - `arguments[0]` in this case is `webElement`.

Answer (score 3):

For executeScript API: `executeScript(script/function, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)`

The first argument is a javascript snippet or a javascript function, if it's a javascript snippet, it will be wrapper into an javascript function inside `executeScript`.

The next arguments are the arguments for the javascript function represents the first argument.

`arguments` is javascript function build-in feature. you can use it to get real passed-in arguments when call function. Please see below example:

```
test('tom', 12, 'male', '175cm') // call function: test

function test(name, age) {
  console.log(name); // tom
  console.log(age);  // 12
  console.log(arguments); // ['tom', 12, 'male', '175cm']
  console.log(arguments[0]); // equal to argument: name, so print tom
  console.log(arguments[1]); // equal to argument: age, so print 12
  console.log(arguments[2]); // male
  console.log(arguments[3]); // 175cm
}
```

More detail about Javascript [Function.arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be running in the context of an anonymous function which is getting passed whatever `driver.findElement(locator)` produces.

So, `arguments[0]` is your way of accessing the first argument to the anonymous function and same for `arguments[1]`

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example of using arguments[0] and arguments[2]:

objIE.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", Array(objIE.FindElementById("sqlvalue1"), Sheets("SheetName").Range("U2").Value)