# What is arguments[0] while invoking execute_script() method through WebDriver instance through Selenium and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to crawl the pages that I interested in. For this, I need to remove attribute of element from HTML. 'style' is what I want to remove. So I find some codes from Stackoverflow.(i'm using Chrome for driver)

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='m-tcol-c' and @id='searchBy']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
```

What does **arguments[0]** do in the code? Can anyone explain **arguments[0]**'s roles concretely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`arguments` is what you're passing *from Python* to *JavaScript* that you want to execute.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
```

means that you want to "replace" `arguments[0]` with WebElement stored in `element` variable.

This is the same as if you defined that element in JavaScript:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('select.m-tcol-c#searchBy').removeAttribute('style')")
```

You can also pass more arguments as

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute(arguments[1])", element, "style")
```

Comment: Note the word `WebElement` to be passed to the `execute_script`method. Passing the result from `element(by.css(...))` directly causes CallStackSize error, that's why one has to use `element(by.css(...)).getWebElement()`

Answer (score 2):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='m-tcol-c' and @id='searchBy']")
```

Here, element is a web element.

and in this call:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
```

You are passing **element**(Which is a web element) as a `arguments[0]`

`removeAttribute('style')` must be a method in JS. and using `arguments[0]` you are invoking this method.

Comment: Word 'invoking' helps me to understand **arguments**. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation [**`execute_script()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method *synchronously executes **JavaScript** in the current window/frame* and is defined as:

```
execute_script(script, *args)
    Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.
    Where:
        script: The JavaScript to execute.
        *args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
```

- As per the example you have provided:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='m-tcol-c' and @id='searchBy']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
  ```
- **`arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')`** : Refers to the script to be executed synchronously by `execute_script()` method where:

  - `arguments[]` would be the reference of the element which will be passed through **`*args`**
  - `removeAttribute()` is the method to be executed.
  - `style` is the attribute on which the method `removeAttribute()` would be invoked.
- **`element`** is the reference of the *WebElement* which is passed to `arguments[0]`

> You can find a relevant discussion in [What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro/49873090#49873090)