# Unable to click on Radio Button getting "ElementClickInterceptedException" error

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, splinter, expected-condition

I am getting following error while trying to click on radio button using selenium Webdriver in python

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element 
<input name="gender" required="" type="radio" id="gender-radio-1" class="custom-control-input" value="Male"> 
is not clickable at point (532, 370). Other element would receive the click: <label title="" for="gender-radio-1" class="custom-control-label">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

**Below is the my code**
**page url:**https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form')
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "gender"]')
driver.implicitly_wait(7)
btn.click()
```

Is there any way to work around this? I have tried multiple things but unable to perform the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try forcing the click by executing javascript:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "gender"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

Separately, consider using `WebDriverWait` instead of implicit waits.

Comment: thanks, it worked.Could you please explain why we used arguments[0]

Comment: That's javascript syntax. Think of it as - the first argument you pass to the script is your `btn`. Others have [explained it better than me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273298/what-is-arguments0-while-invoking-execute-script-method-through-webdriver-in)