# Unable to click on shadow root element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on a button which looks like is present inside shadow root. Below is the image where I am trying to click:

[image]

When I trying to click the element above it, getting an error that element is not interactable.

Search any song on amazon prime music for doing it yourself.

Approach 1

```
song_result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/music-app/div[4]/div/div/div/music-container/music-container[2]/div/music-shoveler")
song = song_result.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"music-horizontal-item")
a = song.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"music-button")
a[1].click()
```

Approach 2

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/music-app/div[4]/div/div/div/music-container/music-container[2]/div/music-shoveler/music-horizontal-item[1]/music-button[2]//button").click()
```

Actually the order is like this:

```
<music-horizontal-item>
    <music-button>
        #shadowRoot
        <button>
    <music-button>
        #shadowRoot
        <button>This button I need to click
```

So I used this as per your suggestion

```
song_result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/music-app/div[4]/div/div/div/music-container/music-container[2]/div/music-shoveler")
song = song_result.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"music-horizontal-item")
a = song.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"music-button")
song_root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",a[1])
song_root.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"button").click()a
```

Still getting this error:

```
Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must select shadow dom as element with js then search inside it with selenium `find` function:

**method1**:

```
song = song_result.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"music-button")
song_root = expand_element(song)
a = song_root.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"button")
a[1].click()
```

then write `expand_element` function to execute js script on element and get `shadowRoot` ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273298/what-is-arguments0-while-invoking-execute-script-method-through-webdriver-in))

```
def expand_element(element):
    return driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element)
```

**method2** (direct):

```
song_root = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('music-button').shadowRoot")
a = song_root.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"button")
a[1].click()
```

i can't see parent elements, but what was said was "the structure of finding" in shadow dom

```
music_h_i = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//music-horizontal-item")
music_h_i_expanded = expand_element(music_h_i)
music_button = music_h_i_expanded.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"music-button")
music_button_expanded = expand_element(music_button)
music_button.click() # or music_button_expanded.click()
```

don't need use xpath from `/html/body/`, xpath has very feature for search

Comment: I edited the question based on your suggestion. I think you misunderstood which tag I need to click so I edited the question and some code as per your suggestion but still getting error.
Message: element not interactable

Comment: @EXODIA which element is not interactable?

Comment: @EXODIA see answer, updated