# How to extract a field from xpath which is not present in an element tag?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<div class="info">
    <span class="label">Establishment year</span>
    "2008"
</div>
```

I want to extract 2008 by using xpath but the expression just selects the establishment text.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Establishment year']")
```

Comment: it is inside div content

Comment: try `//div[@class='info']`, because 2008 inside div

Comment: @LucasWieloch I only want to extract 2008 and not the text 'Establishment year'

Comment: @PrakharT yes, and 2008 is inside the div's text node, which means that it is present in an element tag. How could it not be present in an element tag? Anyways, the xpath you want is something like this `//div[@class='info']/text()`. Try it

Comment: but the class 'info' is not unique.The text 'establishment year' is the unique field from where I can reach this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the text **2008** is within a *text node* to extract the text **2008** you can use the following solution:

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='info']/span[@class='label' and text()='Establishment year']/..")))).strip())
```

Comment: I only want to extract 2008 and not the text 'Establishment year'

Comment: @PrakharT What is the output you are getting once you incorporate this line of code?

Comment: can you please share some tutorial for driver.execute_script function?

Comment: @PrakharT Here a few good discussions to start with to understand `execute_script ()` function: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro/49873090#49873090)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [WebDriver](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) does not allow [find_element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) function result to be a Text Node so you will have to go for [execute_script](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebDriver.execute_script) function like:

```
driver.execute_script(
"return  document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='info']/node()[3]\", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;")
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)