# JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function error using arguments[0].click through Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have been webscraping some websites to grab there locations for webscraping practice. This code gets me down to individual city levels of a hotel brand, but whenever I use driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button) in my code (as seen in the second to last line) I get this error:

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

Below is a sample of the code that I have written thus far.

```
for state in state_links:
driver = Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)
link = 'https://www.ihg.com/destinations/us/en/united-states/' + state.lower().replace(' ', '-')
driver.get(link)
city_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="countryListingContainer col-xs-12"]//ul//div//li//a//span')
city_links = [thing.text for thing in city_links]
driver.close()
for city in city_links:
    driver = Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)
    link2 = 'https://www.ihg.com/destinations/us/en/united-states/' + state.lower().replace(' hotels', '').replace(' ', '-') + '/' + city.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    driver.get(link2)
    hotel_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="hotelList-detailsContainer"]//div//div//p//a')
    hotel_links = [elem.text for elem in hotel_links]
    driver.close()
    for hotel in hotel_links:
        driver = Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)
        driver.get(link2)
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", hotel)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error message...

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

...implies that invoking *click()* on `arguments[0]` using `execute_script()` failed.

---

A bit of more information about the steps would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. However, presumably as you are collecting the `hotel_links` just after:

```
driver.get(link2)
hotel_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="hotelList-detailsContainer"]//div//div//p//a')
```

So initially, `hotel_links` contains the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). But in the next line you are overwriting the *List* `hotel_links` with the *elem.text* as follows:

```
hotel_links = [elem.text for elem in hotel_links]
```

So, `hotel_links` now contains elements of type **text**.

As *text* element doesn't support `click()`, hence moving forward when you try to invoke `click()` on the text elements through `execute_script()`, you see the said error.

---

### Solution

If you need the *text* of the hotel links, store them in a seperate *List* asfollows:

```
hotel_links_text = [elem.text for elem in hotel_links]
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-argument-0-and-argument-1-mean-in-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium-w/49873090#49873090)