# What does execute_script() in Selenium does

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```py
browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab2');")
browser.switch_to.window("tab2")
browser.get('http://bing.com')
```

I was searching online ways to open a new tab using selenium in python, and the method of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>t</kbd> wasn't working on chrome so I stumbled on the above piece of code, however I am not able to understand what 'excute_script' does.

Comment: See the link below for the javascript documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 14):

`execute_script` method allows to execute JavaScript passed as string argument

Note that you can pass data from Python code into JavaScript code using `arguments`, e.g.

```
hello = "Hello"
friends = " friends"

browser.execute_script('alert(arguments[0], arguments[1]);', (hello,  friends))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### execute_script()

[execute_script()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) synchronously executes *JavaScript* in the current window/frame.

```
execute_script(script, *args)

where:
    script: The JavaScript to execute
    *args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
```

This method is [defined](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.execute_script) as:

```
   def execute_script(self, script, *args):
       """
       Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.

       :Args:
        - script: The JavaScript to execute.
        - \\*args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.

       :Usage:
           ::

               driver.execute_script('return document.title;')
       """
       if isinstance(script, ScriptKey):
           try:
               script = self.pinned_scripts[script.id]
           except KeyError:
               raise JavascriptException("Pinned script could not be found")

       converted_args = list(args)
       command = None
       if self.w3c:
           command = Command.W3C_EXECUTE_SCRIPT
       else:
           command = Command.EXECUTE_SCRIPT

       return self.execute(command, {
           'script': script,
           'args': converted_args})['value']
```

---

### Examples

A couple of examples:

- To open a new blank *tab*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")
  ```
- To open a new *tab* with an url:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com');")
  ```
- To retrieve the page title:

  ```
  driver.execute_script('return document.title;')
  ```
- To scroll inti view an element:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element)
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro/49873090#49873090)
- [What is JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089)