# Running a "for" loop in JavaScript through Python-Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Javascript to collate data from an HTML page via Selenium; however, I cannot run the Javascript portion from my computer via Selenium/py cause Python only offers the `driver.execute_script('string of a script')`, whereas I have a multi-line for loop which won't execute with these commands.

The loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
    if (Values[i].getAttribute('automation-id') === 'contact-wealth-manager') {
        ele = Values[i]
    }
}
```

As you can test, this won't work with the standard "driver.execute_script("let value = '';")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute the multiline loop *Javascript* you need to pass the script as an argument to [execute_script()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987951/what-does-execute-script-in-selenium-does/64988955#64988955) method as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("""
    for (let i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
        if (Values[i].getAttribute('automation-id') === 'contact-wealth-manager') {
            ele = Values[i]
        }
    }
""")
```