# Execute Javascript using Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm loading a page using selenium and I want to execute this

```
<script>
var ep_start = $('#episode_page a.active').attr('ep_start');
var ep_end = $('#episode_page a.active').attr('ep_end');
var id = $("input#movie_id").val();
var default_ep = $("input#default_ep").val();
var alias = $("input#alias_anime").val();
loadListEpisode('#episode_page a.active',ep_start,ep_end,id,default_ep,alias);
</script>
```

I have no clue how to do it in python, I tried to use the full script

```
js = '''script'''
browser.execute_script(js)
```

or just loadListEpisode(...) replacing each one by its equivalent, it's not really working.
The script is present on the page so maybe there's a way to directly call it.
I tried to extract ep_start, ep_end,.. by hand then doing this

```
source = BeautifulSoup(...)
var1 = source.find(...)
...
browser.execute_script("loadEpisodeList(var1,var2,...)")
```

It didn't work too, I don't think it's recognizing them as variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$` represents `jQuery`, you would first have to load it into the browser as follows *if it has not already been loaded by the current page*:

```py
path_to_jquery_js = '/my_scripts/jquery.js' # for example
with open(path_to_jquery_js, 'r') as f:
    jquery_js = r.read()
browser.execute_script(jquery_js)
```

If you do not have jQuery stored locally, then you would have to use something like the `requests` module from the `PyPi` repository to fetch it:

```py
import requests

jquery_url = 'https://some_domain/jquery.js' # for example
r = requests.get(jquery_url)
jquery_js = r.text
browser.execute_script(jquery_js
```

Then you should be able to execute the script as follows:

```py
script = """
var ep_start = $('#episode_page a.active').attr('ep_start');
var ep_end = $('#episode_page a.active').attr('ep_end');
var id = $("input#movie_id").val();
var default_ep = $("input#default_ep").val();
var alias = $("input#alias_anime").val();
loadListEpisode('#episode_page a.active',ep_start,ep_end,id,default_ep,alias);
"""

browser.execute_script(script)
```

Just make sure `loadListEpisode` is already defined by other JavaScript that has already been loaded.

This is untested by me for obvious reasons, but give it a shot -- it should work in principle. Let me know how it goes (I am sure you will).

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pass the script as an argument to [execute_script()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987951/what-does-execute-script-in-selenium-does/64988955#64988955) method as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("""
var ep_start = $('#episode_page a.active').attr('ep_start');
var ep_end = $('#episode_page a.active').attr('ep_end');
var id = $("input#movie_id").val();
var default_ep = $("input#default_ep").val();
var alias = $("input#alias_anime").val();
loadListEpisode('#episode_page a.active',ep_start,ep_end,id,default_ep,alias);
""")
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to extract and print the final numbers using Selenium ChromeDriver and MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177092/how-to-extract-and-print-the-final-numbers-using-selenium-chromedriver-and-mutat)

Comment: Thanks to you too, It worked.

Comment: @IliasOukil No matter what, generally my codes are well tested before being published ;)