# Python Selenium, edge browser, I dont see Inspect Element on every element

Tags: python, html, windows, selenium, powerbi

1. I am trying to get data from a Power Bi table. There are some elements that appear when hovering over a table. When I right click on `...` I don't see `Inspect Element`. However, when I left click on this element, I can see a menu, and if I right click on any items, I can see `Inspect element`.
   My first question, is why I don't see `Inspect Element` in the right click menu for all elements in the browser. Am I somehow able to open this `...` menu programmatically in Selenium?
2. the Export Data element only appears in HTML after the first left click. I'm assuming this is created using Javascript and in order to export data with Selenium I would have to programmatically instantiate this by clicking on the `...` menu. Is selenium capable of triggering javascript functions that generate more html code in a dynamic webpage? Or do I need to somehow click on the `...` element.
3. If I can execute a javascript function, how can I find out in Edge the javascript function that gets executed and how can I replicate this function in Selenium

Essentially, if I try to find the `Export data` element in Selenium, it is not able to find it, unless I set a breakpoint before search, then in EdgeDriver I open this menu, and then I can find it and click it through Python

4. If all else fails, can I programmatically open the left click menu by automating a mouse click at certain coordinates in Selenium?

[image: ... right click doesn't have Inspect Element]

[image: The left click menu does have inspect element]

Comment: 1) Could be an event handler on right-click.  Just keep the inspector (dev tools tab) open and click it.  It will highlight the element you clicked on... and/or you can trace back the event to the DOM object.  2) Yes.  You'd click just as the user would... webdriverwaits are used to wait for dynamic JS content to appear.  3) You don't need to replicate the javascript function, only the event (in this case a click)   4) Probably not all that useful to use coords, but you can if you like... these will vary based on resolution so may be good for only one machine.

Comment: Please post a link to a website where we can reproduce the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

**1.1 why I don't see `Inspect Element` in the right click menu for all elements:**
PowerBi has its own context menu so they suppress the browsers context menu. If the element is tricky to find the dev tools, you can press Ctrl + Shift + C (while dev tools is open) and then click the desired element. Your mouse needs to be already over the element before pressing the key combination.
[image: dev tools inspect elements with hotkeys]

**1.2 Am I somehow able to open this `...` menu programmatically in Selenium?**
Seems a little tricky, but could work if you first find the title of that area and move the mouse there, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261754/12914172

Then your element should be in the html and you can find it hopefully by its class name `vcMenuBtn` that seems to be unique on that page. But you need to verify that.

**2. Is selenium capable of triggering javascript functions that generate more html code in a dynamic webpage? Or do I need to somehow click on the `...` element.**
Selenium is able to execute javascript like desribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70544802/12914172

However in your sample, and I was quickly checking the PowerBI online page, this looks like a whole lot of reverse engineering to understand and can sometimes be dangerous as well. I would go for hoover over the area find the `...` and click it.

**3. How can I find out in Edge the javascript function that gets executed**
In dev tools you can set breakpoints to debug the steps the pages does after an action. But again, I would not invest to much time in that.
[image: debugging in dev tools]

**4. Can I programmatically open the left click menu by automating a mouse click at certain coordinates in Selenium?**
Yes but this never works as good as the way described above. If you still want to give it a try, maybe that answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26385456/12914172

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I have not yet succeeded. All elements seem to be within an iframe which I probably have to use as source (main url) for Selenium but the url of this iframe is extremely long and only returns the PowerBI loading icon, no elements (<iframe src="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=c2e93d18-...etc</iframe>. I understand that this is stubborn of me but I will try the coordinates route now. Or accept that I have to manually download the data each day.

Comment: iframe is not a problem. You just need to switch to the right iframe like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834542/12914172
With xpath you can get all iframes back and if there is no other iframe you can just pick the first one that got back. If there are multiple iframes inside each other you need to take one step at a time.

Comment: I don't have iframes in my PowerBI but this might help:
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

Comment: I only realised now, that the url to your PowerBI is in the bounty text... Sorry for that. There is only one iframe, so the code above should work.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to r000bin, this solution works for me, downloading data from PowerBI using Selenium for Python:

```
import selenium, mouse, time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://dataport.gasunie.nl/Vulling-Gasopslagen-Nederland'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(service=Service())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
#driver.fullscreen_window()
#driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
time.sleep(4)
iframe = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
assert len(iframe)==1
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe[0])
time.sleep(4)

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html'), 0,0)
actions.move_by_offset('5', '5').click().perform()
    
time.sleep(4)
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'vcMenuBtn')
button.click()
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, '0')
button.click()

# 4 tabs and 1 enter
time.sleep(4)
for n in range(4):
    element = driver.switch_to.active_element
    time.sleep(2)
    element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    time.sleep(2)

element = driver.switch_to.active_element
time.sleep(2)
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.close()
```