# JavaScriptException in execute_script method

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

```
def send(self, message):
    try:
        textArea = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='Message...']")
        textArea.clear()
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='" + message + "'", textArea) # Error right here
        textArea.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
        sendButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Send')]").click()

    except NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException as ex:
        print("Исключение в send()")
        print(ex)
```

Up to this point, the fifth line worked, but now I just can’t figure out what the problem is. And the variables have correct values.

```
File "D:\PROJECTS\BLD_Project\main.py", line 187, in send
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='" + message + "'", textArea)
  File "D:\PROJECTS\INST\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 878, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "D:\PROJECTS\INST\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\PROJECTS\INST\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Does `message` happen to contain quotes, newlines or other "special" characters?

Comment: @Thomas can you provide a list of special characters? It looks like you are right.

Comment: @Thomas message contains a quote character written as \'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be running into escaping troubles. If `message` contains a quote character, for example `O'Hara`, you'd end up with a syntax error in the executed JavaScript code:

```
arguments[0].value='O'Hara'
```

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988072/14637) is to use the `arguments` array that you're already using, to pass the `message` string as well:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", textArea, message)
```

Comment: it's difficult for me to understand this behavior, where exactly did I go wrong ?

Comment: moreover, I run the code that I have given, with multiple combination of special characters and it did work on those occasions as well.

Comment: Do you understand why `arguments[0].value='O'Hara'` is a problem?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `message` is a string, you can use `setAttribute` inside `execute_script` like below:

```
textArea = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='Message...']")
self.driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{message}')", textArea)
```

to pass `message` variable into `textArea` web element.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: It does not address the problem. If the original code gives a syntax error, so will this one.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't see any syntax error, I made a sample.html file with an input tag and could update the input field with my selenium script having execute_script, whatever I have mentioned above. It did work and did not throw any syntax error.

Comment: If you didn't see any syntax error, you were failing to reproduce OP's issue in the first place. Read the question again. What happened if you set `message = "O'Hara"` in your Python code?

Comment: @Thomas: See by yourself, updated with screenshot.

Comment: he had problem at this line `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='" + message + "'", textArea) # Error right here` and I could resolve this, I am not here to make you agree on this, but I don't see anyway you should downvote this answer. Cause this actually works.

Comment: It works _exactly as well as the original code_. Not worse, but also not better. Which is: fine if `message` is `This is stackoverflow`, and broken if `message` is `O'Hara`.

Comment: @Thomas: Again updated! with multiple special character combinations.

Comment: The screenshot is meaningless; the syntax error is not in the Python code. `arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'This is stack'ove'rfl'ow')` is now the JavaScript you're producing. Which will fail as soon as the browser tries to run it. (Here ends my will to discuss this further.)

Comment: @Thomas: that's the point, it did work with my sample.html file but anyway, I can not spend my precious time on this. You are right !