# Python: how to open new tab without waiting for current tab page loading in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

I am opening 10 tabs (same URL) in chrome browser Successfully. but problem is that, my URL takes 1 minute to load page and i don't want to wait 1 minute at each tab.

i need to let it load and want to open another tab and i know final tab compulsory take one minute to load but no problem but i don't want to wait 1 minute for each tab.

what can i do to achieve it?

i have used `time.sleep()`, `WebDriverWait`, `driver.switch_to.window(x)` but no use.

Thanks in Advance

This is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common import window
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
url = 'http://my_url/Index'
driver.get(url)
for _ in range(10):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.switch_to.new_window(window.WindowTypes.TAB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks likley that you will need to create a thread for each time you open a URL

```
import threading

def main(url)
  # use a different driver for each thread
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
  driver.get(url)
  rand_function1
  return

url = "http://my_url/Index"
for t in range(10):
   t = threading.Thread(target=main, args=[url])
   t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks lot. it is opening 10 browsers but my requirement is to open 10 tabs in one (same) browser

Answer (score 0):

To get rid from waiting for the opened tab to be loaded you need to apply `NONE` [`PageLoadStrategy`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities_exports_PageLoadStrategy.html). By default `NORMAL` `PageLoadStrategy` is used. By definition in this case `WebDriver should wait for the document readiness state to be "complete" after navigation` while you want `WebDriver should not wait on the document readiness state after a navigation event` strategy.
To apply this `PageLoadStrategy` to your code this should be added to your code:

```py
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
```

This is how looks the entire code on my side. It works as desired

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=caps, service=s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to open a/multiple new tab(s) without waiting for current tab page loading using Python Selenium would be to use [*execute_script()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987951/what-does-execute-script-in-selenium-does/64988955#64988955) method as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
  for _ in range(10):
      driver.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: fast_tabs]