# Select in Python, IEDriverServer 4.8 returns "an unexpected error"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, iedriverserver

While running the Python code on Edge browser in IE mode get the error:
*"Cannot click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function returned an unexpected error, but no error could be returned from Internet Explorer's JavaScript engine"*

This code:

```
def my_select(self, text):
    self.app.select_from_drop_down('//select[@class="gender"]', text)
```

calls this one:

```
def select_from_drop_down(self, selector, text):
    wd = self.wd
    if text is not None:
        Select(wd.find_element(By.XPATH, selector)).select_by_visible_text(text)
```

and in the test I call the my_select method:

```
def test_select_male(app):
    app.people_page.open_page()
    app.people_page.my_select('Male')
```

DOM:

```
                      <select class="gender">
                         <option></option>
                         <option name="MALE">Male</option>
                         <option name="FEMALE">Female</option>
                      </select>
```

This is a know bug, that was reported to selenium developers. But it's not fixed.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10319
People have found work around for Java and published it in the comments.

I have tried to write a work around for this bug in Python using *execute_script*, but never succeeded.

```
def select_from_drop_down_menu(self):
    btn = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="MALE"]').click()
    wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you are using _IE7 compatibility mode_ but not _IE 11_ mode?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium, I have never said it's IE7
Update: you are right, it's just IE mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of the [`execute_script()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988955/7429447) method as follows:

```
def select_from_drop_down(self, selector, text):
    wd = self.wd
    if text is not None:
     wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", wd.find_element(By.XPATH, selector))
```

And you can continue calling it as:

```
def test_select_male(app):
    app.people_page.open_page()
    app.people_page.my_select('Male')
```

and further:

```
def my_select(self):
    self.app.select_from_drop_down('//select[@class="gender"]//option[text()='Male']', text)
```

Comment: Hi! 
The test passes, I mean no errors displayed, but the drop down is not clicked and option is not selected. :(